# Чистка неиспользуемых стилей

Tags: gulp

Привет!
Вопрос следующего характера:
Есть сайт с множеством внутренних страниц, есть файл стилей, общий для всего сайта, в котором за время жизни накопилось много неактуальных строк. Хочу избавиться от мусора и разделить стили для разделов сайта на самостоятельные файлы. Для данной задачи использую gulp с плагином [gulp-uncss](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-uncss) и хочу оптимизировать действия.

Необходимо задать в gulpfile.js параметр, который определит страницы, среди которых uncss будет выбирать используемые стили

сейчас таск выглядит примерно так:

```
gulp.task('uncss', function () {
return gulp.src('style.css')
    .pipe(uncss({
        html: ['http://mysite.com/', 'http://mysite.com/**', 'http://mysite.com/**/**', 'http://mysite.com/**/**/**/']
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('css')); });
```

но рекурсивно при этом все страницы не проходит

подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно написать таск чтоб избежать принудительного прописывания всех url. Хочу добиться рекурсии при проверке сайта

Comment: может так `http://mysite.com/**/*.html` еще у вас кажется ошибка в `.pipe(gulp.dest('css')); });` скорее должно быть так `.pipe(gulp.dest('css'));`

Comment: @stackanon ответ разработчика на гитхабе https://github.com/giakki/uncss/issues/264
всё-таки нет такого функционала